# How do I sign in using urllib and then access webpages using that authority in Python?

Tags: python, web, urllib

So, what I want to do is sign in to Wallbase.cc and then get the tags for a NSFW wallpaper (you need to be signed in for that). It seems as if I can sign in fine but when I try to access the wallpaper page it throws up a 403 error. This is the code I'm using:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib
import re

username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
payload = {
    'csrf' : '371b3b4bd0d1990048354e2056cd36f20b1d7088',
    'ref' : 'aHR0cDovL3dhbGxiYXNlLmNjLw==',
    'username' : username,
    'password' : password
    }
login_data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
req = urllib2.Request('http://wallbase.cc/user/login', login_data)

url = "http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/2098029"

#Opens url of each pic
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
```

Any idea?
Btw the wallpaper used isn't actually NSFW it was incorrectly flagged.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

here is an exemple :

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
# follow second link with element text matching regular expression
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"cheese\s*shop", nr=1)
assert br.viewing_html()
print br.title()
print response1.geturl()
print response1.info()  # headers
print response1.read()  # body

br.select_form(name="order")
# Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
# to the selected HTMLForm.
br["cheeses"] = ["mozzarella", "caerphilly"]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
# Submit current form.  Browser calls .close() on the current response on
# navigation, so this closes response1
response2 = br.submit()

# print currently selected form (don't call .submit() on this, use br.submit())
print br.form

response3 = br.back()  # back to cheese shop (same data as response1)
# the history mechanism returns cached response objects
# we can still use the response, even though it was .close()d
response3.get_data()  # like .seek(0) followed by .read()
response4 = br.reload()  # fetches from server

for form in br.forms():
print form
# .links() optionally accepts the keyword args of .follow_/.find_link()
for link in br.links(url_regex="python.org"):
print link
    br.follow_link(link)  # takes EITHER Link instance OR keyword args
    br.back()
```

Comment: I saw mechanize before but figured that it'd be easier to just stick with urllib. I may take a deeper look into it if urllib doesn't work...